# How to rotate an image about arbitrary point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I Want to rotate an image on an arbitrary point in JavaScript. I am using save and restore APIs, but it rotates the image according to input angle not about center point(arbitrary point).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

Comment: check this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579449/rotate-image-with-center-point-in-javascript